# How to test an Object/Class with all the posible constructor arguments permutations?

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest, python-unittest

I have the next class that I want to test with `pytest`:

```py
class Analysis(object, metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):

    def __init__(self, filters, and_operator, filters_comb_type):
        self.filters = filters
        self.andOperator = and_operator
        self.filtersComb_type = filters_comb_type

    def _generate_defaultfilters_combination(self):
        ...

    def _generate_allfilters_combinations(self):
        ...

    def _check_filters(self, pattern_indexes, direction=None):
        ...
```

So, I want to create a lot of possible Analysis() with a different set of possible values for `filters`, `and_operator` and `filters_comb_type`.

So I have written the next code using pytest:

```py
import pytest
from src.statistical_analysis.analysis import Analysis, FiltersCombinationType
from tests.analysis_filters.mocks_analysis_filter import *


@pytest.fixture(params=[[],
                        [MockAllwaysTrueAnalysisFilter()],
                        [MockAllwaysFalseAnalysisFilter()],
                        [MockEvenTrueOddFalseAnalysisFilter()],
                        [MockAllwaysTrueAnalysisFilter(), MockAllwaysFalseAnalysisFilter(), MockAllwaysFalseAnalysisFilter()]])
def filters(request):
    return request.param


@pytest.fixture(params=[True, False])
def and_operator(request):
    return request.param


@pytest.fixture(params=[FiltersCombinationType.ONLY_DEFAULTS,
                        FiltersCombinationType.ONE_COMBINATION,
                        FiltersCombinationType.ALL_COMBINATIONS])
def filters_comb_type(request):
    return request.param


@pytest.fixture
def analysis():
    a = Analysis(filters, and_operator, filters_comb_type)
    return a
```

So, if I have understand well the analysis() fucntion will create all the possible combinations of Analysis() object.

But my problem comes when I want to write the code to test the 3 methods of Analysis class, beause if I write this:

```py
def test_check_filters(analysis):
    ...
```

The test it's going to be called with each of the whole Analysis objects created in the fixture, but now how can I compare each Analsysis with his expected return value of the `check_filters()` method??

I want to know which one is the correct aproach when we want to test a method of a class creating a lot of instances of a class with differente constructor parameters.

Comment: But you didn't provide the expected values anywhere, or am I wrong?

Comment: Besides, I guess the `analysis` fixture should look like `def analysis(filters, and_operator, filters_comb_type): ...`?

Comment: @hoefling that is what I want to know how to do it? How is the best way (efficiently, orderly and scalable) to do it? [and thanks for the bug in the analysis funciton() :)]

Comment: You can e.g. introduce another fixture `def expected_value(analysis)` where you select the expected value from some dict and use the fixture in test in addition to the others.